# Dynamic Views created from Service not getting Garbage Collected

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-service

I am working with Dynamic Views. I am running a service. When that service receive a Broadcast, I add Myview to window manager and remove that after user perform some action. But since service keeps running, I am adding this dynamic view 'myView', every-time I get broadcast. The problem is that they are not getting garbage collected after removing them from window manager and Heap Memory allocation getting increased continuously. Not sure why? Since it has bitmap inside it. After 5-6 actions I am getting OutOfMemoryException.

```
   public class Myservice extends Service{                                                        
       private ParentView myView;
       WakeReceiver receiver;

        @Override
        public void onCreate()
        {
          super.onCreate();
          registerBroadCastReceiver();
        }


        //Performed when broadcast recieved
        public void addLayout() {
           WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
           myView = new ParentView(this);
           windowManager.addView(myView, getLayoutParam());

        }

        //Performed when user performs action on ParentView
        public void removeLayout() {
           WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
           windowManager.removeView(myView);

        }

         private void registerBroadCastReceiver() {
             IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

             receiver = new WakeReceiver();
             registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        }

         private WindowManager.LayoutParams getLayoutParam() {
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new     WindowManager.LayoutParams();

                 localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                 localLayoutParams.height = (int) (WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                 return localLayoutParams;

        }


}
```

//Code for Parent View

```
 public class ParentView extends RelativeLayout {


      MyService topService;  

      public ParentView(MyService topService) {
         super(topService);
         this.topService = topService;
         LayoutInflater.from(topService).inflate(R.layout.parent_layout, this);                 

           setBackgroundDrawable(topService.getResources()
              .getDrawable(R.drawable.sample_image));
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
         topService.removeLayout();  
      }



}
```

Comment: Please provide code of ParentView. Looks like you are storing a link to some resources there and that's prevent a garbage collection.

Comment: Does the `removeView` method have any effect? I mean, does the view gets actually removed?

Comment: `static` doesn't get gc unless the process is finished you have to null it in ondestroy.

Comment: again I made it non-static it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `system.gc();` This helps me once. It invoke the garbage collector. Try it and reply me if it works.

Comment: Call it before creating a view.

Comment: Did you use finally block. Kindly do one more thing. in your finally block. set bitmap to null.And then call system.gc();

Comment: Also check this link https://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/network/prirucky/javatut/java/system/garbage.html

Comment: Problem is not the bitmap. If I remove bitmap from view. still it is crashing     after 50-60 actions of 'screen turned-off'.

Comment: Your approach will not work. Please read first about how System.gc() works. largeheap=true also will not solve the problem.

Comment: @Stepango . Then post a solution or try to to help. Rather then giving negative ratings.

Comment: @NoumanGhaffar, don't take the downvote as something personal towards you. It's just a method to indicate that your answer is not helpful. People with experience in Java and Android development usually know that manual call to GC is not encouraged. If there is a memory leak, GC will not be able to help. System probably calls it multiple times before the OOM anyway.